# Need to format timespan ADO.NET datacolumn as AM/PM

Tags: .net, datetime, ado.net

I have a DataTable with a DataColulmn of TimeSpan type. It gets filled with a time column in a SQL Server query, and it shows as a 24 hr format on screen. I wanted to show it as a 12 hr format + am/pm using an expression column, but coulnd't do it.
I tried using convert to the column to handle the string, but it shows a strange format such as PT20H15 (that would be 20:15 or 8:15 pm). As the position of time and hour changes if the hour is one or two digits, and if hour is 00 then it get removed, string handling seems like too complicated. I tried just comparing the column value like "HourCol > 12" but that raises an error regarding comparing timespan to int, so I failed again. Does anyone have a different suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, or other?  It matters in how you accomplish this.  How a DateTime value is displayed is dependent on the program actually displaying it, more than on the underlying value.  You CAN convert it to a varchar in teh SQL Query you use to get it out, but that's not always the best way to do it.

Comment: @David I show the data on a grid on a ASP.NET page. Users can edit the data on separate controls, and then I save the values back to SQL Server. I rather have an expression column so I don't have to make a double convertion, just update the original column on my datatable... if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it shows a strange format such as PT20H15

That's not a strange format at all. It's an ISO-8601 format for a period, which is fairly reasonable for a `TimeSpan`.

> I wanted to show it as a 12 hr format + am/pm

That sounds like you're using a `TimeSpan` for a "time of day", which is far from ideal to be honest. I know it's what `DateTime.TimeOfDay` gives, but that's just because the framework doesn't have a "time only" type, worse luck.

> Does anyone have a different suggestion?

Can you have a computed column which is basically some fixed date (or even `DateTime.Today`) + the timespan value, and format that using a `hh:mm tt` format? (Could you manually overwrite the values yourself in the `DataTable`, perhaps, rather than using a computed expression?)

Another alternative would be to change your SQL query to do the conversion to a date/time value, rather than doing it in the `DataTable`.

Comment: I went with the add a bogus date idea. Thanks!