# EF Time primitive type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have problem with creating column in EntityFamework with Time type
I am able to create columns with types like : string, int, DateTime without problems.

But how to create column with Time type?

```
public class OrdinacniHodiny : ValidityEntity<long>
{
     [Required]
     //[Required, DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{hh:mm}")]
     public Time CasOd { get; set; }
     /// <summary>
     /// Required
     /// 
     /// formát hh:mm
     /// </summary>

     [Required]
     public DateTime CasDo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL 'time' type in Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186044/sql-time-type-in-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: Do you actually need Time type in Sql or do you just want to store a time

Comment: I need something which is similar to DateTime, but without date. Only Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your `CasOd` property as follows:

```
[Required]
public TimeSpan CasOd { get; set; }
```

Comment: You are right, I have tried this earlier, but didnt work becouse I had problem in database.