# How to map `time(0)` to `DateTime` with Entity Framework 6

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, datetime

Is there any way a custom mapping rule could be injected using Entity Framework 6's new dependency pattern?

The database I am working with has times of day stored in a few `time(0)` columns.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx), the `time` data type defines a particular “*time of a day*”, as opposed to an arbitrary *length of time*. This is evidenced by the range of the `time` type, 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999.

All is well here. However, Entity Framework refuses to map it to a `DateTime` property.

The mapping to the ADO.NET default of `TimeSpan` is far from ideal (as [Jon Skeet pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12078643/521757)) because SQL Server's `time` is not an arbitrary span of time but has AM/PM context. .NET's `TimeSpan` formatter has no concept of AM/PM. `time` and `TimeSpan` are for separate problem domains. From a purely idealistic point of view, I would rather always map `time` to `DateTime`. That also makes sense because of the fixed starting point as a time of day.

Worse, because of these separate problem domains of `time` and `TimeSpan`, controls like DevExpress's TimeEdit will only bind to `DateTime` properties. I am hoping to avoid dirtying all my entities with duplicated properties that simply translate between `TimeSpan` and `DateTime`.

(The author here asked the same question but had fewer requirements:
[SQL 'time' type in Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186044/sql-time-type-in-entity-framework-code-first))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem looks very like the example used to change the convention for DateTimes on this page: [Custom Code First Conventions (EF6 onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx)

Something like this perhaps:

```
public class TimeSpanConvention : Convention
{
    public TimeSpanConvention()
    {
        this.Properties<TimeSpan>()
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime"));        
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new TimeSpanConvention());
}
```

**EDIT** Just re-read your question, and I see that you want DateTime in the C# code and time(0) in the database not the other way around so that won't work. Unfortunately, I suspect you will need 2 fields like this solution [Convert value when mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19377226/150342) - which does keep the database property private.

What about the original idea of a custom coding convention but based on a naming convention:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
                .Where(p => p.Name.EndsWith("TimeOfDay"))
                .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("time(0)"));
}
```

**EDIT 2**
    And since that is an invalid mapping that leaves us with little choice:

In the Model:

```
private string DBTimeOfDay { get; set; }

[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
public DateTime TimeOfDay
{
    get { return new DateTime(DBTimeOfDay.Ticks); }
    set { DBTimeOfDay= value.TimeOfDay; }
}
```

And in the Context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{      modelBuilder.Types().Configure(c =>
   {
      var properties = c.ClrType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                                         | BindingFlags.Instance)
                             .Where(p => p.Name == "DBTimeOfDay");
       foreach (var p in properties)
           c.Property(p).HasColumnName("TimeOfDay");
   });
}
```

Another option is to create a database view that converts `time(0)` to `DateTime` in its sql, and map to modified stored procedures for updates. That technique has been suggested for [unsupported data types](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/yes-you-can-read-and-probably-write-spatial-data-with-entity-framework/)

**EDIT 3 !**
Having slept on this...here are my thoughts.

time(0) represents a time of day.

Entity Framework has chosen to convert it to a `Timespan`.

`Timespan`s are supposed to represent durations.

`Timespans` are easily added to `DateTime`s with the result being a new `DateTime`

C# does not have a `TimeOfDay` data type

So in your business logic either you have to hold time of day' as a `TimeSpan` that never exceeds 24 hours or as a `DateTime` where you have set the date part to an arbitrary value that you then ignore.

EF is consistent with C# where `DateTime.TimeOfDay` returns a Timespan

If you are doing any arithmetic in the business logic, say for recurring appointments or such, then I think there may actually be a marginally stronger argument for TimeSpan. If it's complicated then maybe you should start using [Noda time](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/userguide/rationale.html)

The problem comes when it moves to the UI. `TimeEdit` needs a `DateTime`...We want to display it as a.m./p.m...

So that is where I would map it to a DateTime i.e. in the UI. I'm using MVC. I'm using ViewModels. I'm already mapping from Entities. I'm using AutoMapper. It's easy and it keeps the Entities clean. `TimeSpan` properties in the Domain converted to `DateTime` for UI..

Comment: I could dirty the database, or the entities, or the program logic- but I'm hoping there's a way to get rid of the problem in the first place.

Comment: If fluent mapping worked, it wouldn't be a problem to map the properties individually either. However, there is a runtime error saying error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.DateTime[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=]' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.time[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=7]'

Comment: `DateTime` in the database or duplicated properties to translate between `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` it is then...

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on modifying EF's behaviour via dependency?